# Applying CALayer compositingFilter correctly on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer, cifilter

I have an NSView. It has a layer. Inside of the layer, there are several sublayers. One of those sublayers needs to blend with the layers beneath it. I've set the top layer's `compositingFilter` property, but no blending happens. :-(

Here's a visual representation:

```
Root Layer      <-- myView.layer
|- Bottom Layer <-- myView.layer.sublayers[0]
|- Middle Layer <-- myView.layer.sublayers[1]
|- Top Layer    <-- myView.layer.sublayers[2]

Root Layer
|- Bottom Layer
|- Middle Layer
|- Top Layer    <-- Added filter to this layer.
```

I set the property like so:

```
self.topLayer.compositingFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMultiplyBlendMode"];
```

I assumed that the input image and background image would be supplied automatically with the `contents` of each of the layers, but maybe I'm wrong. Am I?

TL;DR: How does a n00b composite a stack of layers together using blending modes?

P.S. I'm drawing the `contents` of each layer using the delegate method, `-drawLayer:inContext:`.

Comment: You're not wrong. input image is set automatically. shouldn't When do you set the filter? Do you call setNeedsDisplay after that? Did you try setting an image as contents? What I found helping is to send `setDefaults` to the filter before adding it to the layer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag you have to enable on NSView for it use filters on the layer:

```
[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.view setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:YES];
```

I think this is specific to OS X and NSView and isn't necessary with UIView on iOS. Everything else looks correct to me.